# can't get git commit after 4d58e4c about ffserver.c file?

Tags: git, github

I want to get the full revision history of one file, and I use `git log -- filepath` command. However, the result isn't complete.

[image]

As the picture above, the last commit about ffserver.c is 4d58e4c. But from github file history, there are many commits after 4d58e4c. You can check [this link](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commits/cbe43e62c9ac7d4aefdc13476f6f691bd626525f?after=cbe43e62c9ac7d4aefdc13476f6f691bd626525f+34&branch=cbe43e62c9ac7d4aefdc13476f6f691bd626525f&path%5B%5D=ffserver.c) to see.

Ps.I use Fig1 command to just show the latest commit (Fig 1). However, as the github revision history (Fig 2), the git command result(commit 4d58e4c) isn't the latest commit, there are many commits after this commit, such as 094a496 in Fig 2. I want to know why it happens and how i can get the commits after this commit.

[image]

So, how to get these commits using git command or python code and why I can't get the full revision history.

Thanks.

Comment: `git log` command only access the history reachable from the current commit, any commit *after* are not displayed. So you need to retrieve the history from GitHub with `git fetch origin` then search the whole history with `git log --all -- filepath`

Comment: @zigarn thanks!!!!!  I think i need to read more about git book, I'm too weak at this.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Use `git log 4d58e4c..HEAD`, or perhaps `git log 4d58e4c^@..HEAD`.

## Long

Before you just charge off with this recipe, though, it's worth taking some time to learn what this means and how this works.  There are a number of key items to learn:

- Commits are numbered, with random-looking (though actually not random) hash IDs.
- Commits hold snapshots plus metadata:

  - The snapshots hold a full copy of *every* file, but in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.  They therefore act as archives.  These files are not *usable* until they are de-archived (with `git checkout` or `git switch`).  But they can be *visited briefly* while still archived.
  - The metadata winds up stringing the commits together, *backwards*.
- A *branch name* simply holds the hash ID of the *latest* commit on that branch.
- Git works *backwards*.

That last point is why it is so hard to go *forwards*.  Once you have found commit `4d58e4c`, Git can only work *backwards* from it.  So the trick is to work backwards from "now" (most recent commit) until you reach "then" (commit `4d58e4c`).  The commits you visit, in making this trip backwards through time, are the commits that come *after* `4d58e4c`.

#### The backwards nature of commits

As we already noted, each commit has a random-looking hash ID number, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  Git uses this hash ID to locate the commit.  The actual commits are stored in a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database): the hash ID is the key, and the commit's metadata-and-snapshot are the value.<sup>1</sup>

The metadata is *information about the commit:* who made it, when, and so on.  Here you will find the name of the author and committer, and any log message they chose to add, for instance.  One of the metadata *items*, though, is what Git calls the *parent* or *parents* of the commit.  These are the raw hash IDs of some *earlier* commit(s).  Most commits just store one parent hash ID.  The main exception is a *merge commit*, which is defined as any commit storing two or more hash IDs.

Once some commit is made, no part of it can ever be changed.  This is because the hash ID *of* the commit is a simple cryptographic hash of the *contents* (the metadata, including the snapshot).  If you take these bytes out of the key-value database, make some change(s), and put the bytes back in, what you get is not a change to the value under the old key, but rather a *new* commit, with a new hash ID key.  The existing commit remains in the database, still valid and accessible.  All you have done is add a *new* commit.

Since nothing in a commit can ever change after the commit is made, it's literally impossible to put the hash IDs of *newer* commits into *older* commits.  We can only go the other way around.  The newer commit can contain the hash ID the older commit, which we know because the older commit already exists.

When one commit contains another's hash ID, we say that the one commit—necessarily a newer commit, as we just saw—*points to* the older commit.  So to the extent that each commit has just *one* hash ID in it, the commits form a sequence, like pearls on a string, except that we can only go from *newer* commits to *older* ones:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of the *last* commit in the series.  Since commit `H`'s metadata contains the actual hash ID of earlier commit `G`, we say that `H` *points to* `G`.  Meanwhile `G`'s metadata contains the hash ID of commit `F`, so that `G` points backwards to `F`.  This repeats forever, or rather, until we reach the very first commit ever.  It is a special case: it cannot point backwards to anything earlier, so it simply does not point backwards.  It has no parent at all.  This allows Git to stop going backwards.

---

<sup>1</sup>The snapshot is actually found *using* the metadata, through an internal Git *tree object* and another hash ID.  Every commit is required to have exactly one tree, which is that commit's snapshot.  (It might be interesting to allow a commit to store more than one tree, but Git doesn't.)

---

#### Branch names find commits

To find the hash ID of the *last* commit `H`, we could write it down on paper, or on a whiteboard, or something.  Or we could store it in a file.  Or—here's a better idea—we could have *Git* store it somewhere, say, under a *name*.  Let's call that name a *branch name*.  Since we say that commits point to earlier commits, because commits store hash IDs, let's also say that branch names point to commits, because branch names store hash IDs.

This means we can draw our string of <s>pearls</s> commits like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch
```

As long as we have some commit(s) that our names can point-to, we can have as many names as we want.  Some of these names might well point to the *same* commit:

```
...--F   <-- main
      \
       G--H   <-- develop, feature1
```

#### Your HEAD finds a branch name

When we are in the situation we drew above, it's important to know *which branch name we are using*.  We might run `git checkout develop`, for instance.  As briefly mentioned near the top, this checkout operation *extracts* the archived, committed files, turning them into usable every-day files.

The name `develop` currently selects commit `H`.  Our *current branch name* is therefore `develop` and our *current commit* is therefore commit `H`.  To remember this, let's attach the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase, to the name `develop`, like this:

```
...--F   <-- main
      \
       G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), feature1
```

If we run `git checkout feature1`, we are telling Git to select commit `H` via the name `feature1`.  The set of checked out files does not change—commit `H` is still commit `H`—but the *attachment* of `HEAD` changes:

```
...--F   <-- main
      \
       G--H   <-- develop, feature1 (HEAD)
```

If we now go on to make a *new* commit, the new commit will get a new, random-looking hash ID.  We'll just call that `I` here.  The new commit's *parent* will be the commit we had checked out, i.e., commit `H`.  So commit `I` will point back to existing commit `H`.  But look at the magic trick Git performs at the same time:

```
...--F   <-- main
      \
       G--H   <-- develop
           \
            I   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
```

What Git does is that the `git commit` command, as it builds the new commit, sets the new commit's parent to the *current commit*, archives all the files,<sup>2</sup> writes out the appropriate metadata, obtains the new commit's hash ID, and then **writes the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name** as remembered by the attaching of `HEAD`.  So now the *branch name* `feature1` selects new commit `I`.

---

<sup>2</sup>This archiving of files is sneaky: Git uses the copies that are in Git's *index*, not the copies in your working tree.  We have not covered Git's index and your working tree in this answer, but this distinction is important.

---

#### Now we can see how `git log` works

Simplified—by ignoring how `git log` works with merge commits, for instance—what `git log` does is start with some commit you name, or with `HEAD` if you don't name a commit:

```
git log HEAD
```

and:

```
git log
```

both start with the commit found via the name `HEAD`.  Since `HEAD` is normally attached to a branch name,<sup>3</sup> this uses the branch name to find the commit's hash ID.  The `git log` command then shows the commit's metadata.<sup>4</sup>

Then, having shown the commit, Git uses the commit's stored *parent hash ID* to move back one step, to an earlier commit.  If we were on commit `I`, now we are on commit `H`.  The `git log` command will show that commit, then move back one step, to commit `G`.  Then `git log` will show that commit and move back one step, to commit `F`.

Like everything else in Git, then, `git log` simply works *backwards*, one commit at a time.  It stops when you make it stop, or when it reaches the very first commit and thus runs out of commits.

---

<sup>3</sup>When HEAD points directly to a commit hash ID, rather than being attached to a branch name, Git calls this *detached HEAD* mode.  You get this with `git checkout` or `git switch --detach` with a historic commit hash ID, among other methods.  You can use this to inspect the files in existing historical commits, for instance: you are essentially telling Git to un-archive that historical commit, for your use now.  However, if you make a *new* commit in this mode, it's easy to "lose" the new commit later, when you re-attach `HEAD`.

<sup>4</sup>With various options, you can show more or less stuff here.

---

#### More about `git log`

You used:

> ```
> git log -- filepath
> ```

to find a *particular* commit.  The way this works is interesting:

- Each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file.
- Git can, at each commit, compare *this* commit's snapshot with its *parent's* snapshot.  This comparison tells us—or Git—which files *changed*.

With this particular form of `git log`, we tell Git: *Work backwards as usual, but don't **say** anything about a commit unless it changes the file(s) we listed.*  Technically this also performs *History Simplification*, which affects how Git behaves on stepping back through a *merge commit*, but we haven't shown yet how `git log` behaves in other merge commit cases.  (If we don't have any merge commits in the set of commits that `git log` looks at, this doesn't many any difference, but whether or not you have merge commits is not something I can tell from here.)

We can also give `git log` a two-dot *range* notation, of the form `A..B`.  This gets particularly tricky since it involves *reachability*.  For much more about reachability, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  For now, let's just say that `A..B` tells Git log: *start at `B`, but stop before showing commit `A`.*  So:

```
4d58e4c..HEAD
```

means *start at `HEAD` and work backwards*, but also *stop before showing commit `4d58e4c`*.

If you'd like to *see* `4d58e4c` itself, we would like to tell `git log` to stop *after* showing `4d58e4c`.  Since `4d58e4c` has some set of parent(s), and those are the ones *before* `4d58e4c`, if we could tell Git: *start at `HEAD` and work backwards, but stop before showing any commit that's before `4d58e4c`*, that would do the trick.

If `4d58e4c` is *not* a merge commit, `4d58e4c^` or `4d58e4c~1` will work here.  These both mean *the first parent of `4d58e4c`*.  If `4d58e4c` is an ordinary single-parent commit, the *first* parent is the *only* parent, so that's fine.  But if `4d58e4c` is a *merge* commit, `git log` will go on to show the *second* parent.  The special `^@` suffix means *all parents of the given commit*, so `4d58e4c^@` means all parents of `4d58e4c`.  Hence `4d58e4c^@..HEAD` means precisely what we want here, in all cases.